# Derivative of a autoregressive process ARMA(6,6)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I want mathematica to derive the derivative of an ARMA(6,6) process with regards to its parameters. How would I define the function and take the derivative.

Comment: Maybe you could start by defining an ARMA(1,1) process and taking its derivative.

Comment: Yes but the issue is the same when taking the derivative as x_t also has the parameters it will continue to map deeper into the lags.

Comment: Can you write out exactly what equations you want the derivative of?